# JMeter "Do it right"

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, load-testing

How can i know upper bound of requests per second my webapp can handle with JMeter? I am new to it, and it is complex test with production database involved, so i have no right to be wrong. I've created such a configuration: Thread Group with HTTP Request in it and some Listeners. The question is: what parameters do i need to set in Thread Group to complete my test? Do i need to increment number of users step-by-step and re-run my tests? Or do i set an infinite loop? And how can i check server response with Response Assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be a wise idea to do a load test on production database. Not sure why you have this compulsion. Coming on to your problem, I guess you already have answered your question. You *need to increment number of users step-by-step and re-run my tests*. The moment you application breaks ( meaning you do not get the desired response in terms of output and/or response time) that's the upper limit of request for the that particular configuration of software/hardware of your application.

JMeter offers many ways for response assertion. Check out [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) link.